# Is it possible to create StandardValueSetTranslation or GlobalValueSetTranslation in Apex?

Tags: apex, rest, metadata, translation

I've generated apex metadata.service.cls (sth. like this: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls) and now I'm working on REST service for creating new translations of different components.  Generaly I created objects like MetadataService.Translations or MetadataService.CustomObjectTranslation witch extends MetadataService.Metadata, added them to the List and then used on them createMetadata method from MetadataService.MetadataPort object.

I would like to create also StandardValueSetTranslation and GlobalValueSetTranslation objects, but it looks like they don't extends MetadataService.Metadata and because of it I can't use the path I used before. Is there any hope for manipulating this objects through apex?

I would be very gratefull for any help.